# PayPal 401 Unauthorized with credit card payment in live production using .NET REST API for Express checkout API

Tags: asp.net, .net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using .NET REST API for PayPal Express Checkout for direct credit card payment. When I use **sandbox**, I create Payment, set credit card as funding instrument, billing address and payment works fine.
But when I switch to **live**, calling Payment.Create(apiContext) with the exactly same data throws PayPal.IdentityException with 401-Unauthorized message. However, at that time I have valid access token.
Calling regular PayPal payment works fine either using **live** environmnet.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem. It is necessary to determine sdkConfig in apiContext.

```
        var sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "mode", "live" } };
        string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(id, secret, sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();


        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        apiContext.Config = sdkConfig;
```